# Species ID: What's this mushroom?

Tags: species-identification, mycology

So this one is found in white mountain forest in New Hampshire, and I have strong suspicion it is actually just a boletus.

[image]

My question would be what's is the name of this fungus?

Comment: It actually looks very much like a boletus. It should have pores, which I just can't see on your picture. Is that your kitchen? Mind though that not all Boletus are edible...

Comment: There are different types of boletes. For a better answer we would need a picture of the underside and a spore print. Also, specific information about the environment of growth would help.